# Custom View class' onDraw isn't called by Invalidate

Tags: java, android, view, ondraw, android-view-invalidate

Screen is white & the System.out.println() within onDraw in never called.

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<foo.packagename.MyView
    android:id="@+id/myView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

The custom view class:

```
public class MyView extends View {

public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    System.out.println("This line is called");

    while (true) {
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.GREEN);
    System.out.println("This line is never printed");
}
```

The main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("This line is called");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        View myView = findViewById(R.id.myView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get rid of the `while` loop in the constructor.

Comment: That fixed it. I still don't understand what was the issue though

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice until just now that you must've changed your comment while I was replying. Yeah, the answer below explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`invalidate()` does not cause `onDraw()` to be called directly. It just tells the system that the view needs to be redrawn on the next drawing frame. Otherwise on the next drawing frame the system can use what was drawn previously since nothing has changed. In other words, your `invalidate()` call and the eventual `onDraw()` call are asynchronous.

Also, putting an infinite `while` loop in your constructor will cause the UI thread to never execute code beyond that point, so the system will never even complete a single layout pass and your view will never be drawn even once. Needless to say, *do not do this*.